# Is there a portable way to tell if main() has started yet?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

In C++ it's possible to call arbitrary functions at init time before `main()` has been entered, including calls to libraries that are not fully initialized yet, which can cause confusing errors.  If I'm writing a library, is it possible in standard modern C++ (C++20 or so) to tell whether `main()` has started yet, so I can prevent the user of the library from using it before it's safe?

Considered solutions:

- Having a `library::init()` function called at the beginning of `main()`.  The library already works fine without an `init()`, so it seems silly to add one just to improve error reporting.  If nothing else works, obviously this is the best solution.
- Using a static initializer to determine when it's safe to use the library.  It cannot be predicted what order static initializers run in, so this is not reliable.
- Using a function-level static variable to initialize the library (essentially lazy initialization) so that initialization order doesn't matter.  I already do this for some things, but this can't extend the protection to other libraries or system resources that are not usable before `main()`.
- Walking up the stack manually to find a frame for `main()`.  I think not. : )

Comment: Disclosure: This is the second time I've posted this question.  I deleted the first post because it contained too much irrelevant information that distracted readers from the actual question.

Comment: Nope. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Didn't think so, just wanted to make sure nobody else had any ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: C++23 does at least have standard stacktrace support, but hunting through it for `main` is still not portable and also wouldn't handle a different entry point name such as `WinMain`.

Comment: I didn't think of that caveat, that would throw solution #4 out the window if it wasn't out several windows already. : )

Comment: You can do it yourself.  `extern int main_started;` in a header.  `int main_started = 0;` at global scope in your **main.cpp** file.  First line of `main` is `main_started = 1;`.

Comment: This is a library, and the library doesn't have control over `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: from what I gather based on people's comments and looking at

- [Is there any way in C/C++ to detect if code is running during static initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3292204/20738382)
- [How can I call a function or statically initialize an object immediately before main?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14777204/20738382)

it appears that there is no way to get this information in standard C++, and the standard solution is just to provide a `library::init()` function for the user to call in `main()`.

Comment: If this init function is optional and used solely for error reporting, it could have a name reflecting that, such as `library::enhance_error_reporting()`. That said, it will look pretty silly if you ever change the function to become required and/or widen its scope.

Comment: If the goal is to avoid users mistakenly using the library before initialization, you can make it so that accessing any library functionality requires a library handle. Then initialization can either happen as a local static in the constructor of the handle or the initialization can be reference-counted in a static through the handle constructor and destructor. Then it is impossible for a user to call any library function without constructing the handle and initialization the library first, whether it happens in `main` or before it.